# Make all elements of given row numbers equal to NaN

Tags: matlab, matrix, nan

Given a matrix in MATLAB, if any element has a non-finite value, I want to make all elements of that row equal to NaN. For example:

Input:

```
A=[1     2   NaN
  4     5     6
  7   NaN     9
  0     1     2
  3     4     5
  6     7     8
 Inf    0     1
  2     3     4
  5     6     7
  8   NaN     0];
```

Output:

```
B=[NaN NaN   NaN
  4     5     6
 NaN   NaN   NaN
  0     1     2
  3     4     5
  6     7     8
 NaN   NaN   NaN
  2     3     4
  5     6     7
 NaN   NaN   NaN];
```

How can this be done?

This is how I know:

```
idx_NaNinf = find((isnan(A)|isinf(A)) );
[idx_row,idx_col] = ind2sub(size(A),idx_NaNinf);
```

With all row numbers stored in idx_row and by using a for loop, I can make the elements of that row equal to NaN. But is there any other more efficient method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this one-liner:

```
A(any(~isfinite(A), 2), :) = NaN;
```

`~isfinite(A)` returns true for elements of `A` which are infinite or `NaN`. `any(..., 2)` finds all the rows that have such an elements and logical indexing helps to just set the values in those rows to `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks! As an extension, if all columns of a row are zeros, I want to make the entire row NaN. How can I do this?

Input:

   [0     0     1;
    0     0     0;
    7     8     0;
    0     0     0;
    8     9     0;
    0     0     0;
    0     0     0];

Output:

   [0     0     1;
  NaN   NaN   NaN ;
   7     8     0;
  NaN   NaN   NaN ;
   8     9     0;
  NaN   NaN   NaN ;
   NaN   NaN   NaN];

Comment: @Meghana This really gives credit to this answer since it sticks to logical indexing. I almost consider removing my own answer but as far I know it is discouraged. Anyway it is easy to fix, just add a condition for this: `any(~isfinite(a), 2))  | ~any(a,2)`. Not that almost zero will not count here. Then just have something like this instead: `~sum(abs(a)>tol, 2)`. A bit slower, but it should work.

Comment: @patrik I'm sorry, I didn't get you....I have my input as 
`V_in = [0 0 0; 0 1 2; 3 4 5; 0 0 0; 2 3 4; 0 0 0];`

SInce only the first row and last row contain all zeros, they have to be replaced with NaN.

I want my output to be:
`V_out = [NaN NaN  NaN ; 0 1 2; 3 4 5; NaN  NaN  NaN ; 2 3 4; NaN  NaN  NaN ];`

Comment: @Meghana I would really advice you to read through some of the [Matlab Basics](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/getstart.pdf), but regarding your question, you have the condition `~isfinite(A), 2)` in the answer. This one is simply not enough. You also need to check for all-zeros  `~any(A,2)`. So the statement in word should be **"If any value not is finite or not any values is different from zero, then set to NaN"**. Note that `any(v,2)` operates on the second index.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) in MATLAB.

With `A(idx_row,:)` you select all rows which are selected in `idx_row` and all columns of these rows. That's exactly the values you want to set to `NaN`. So it simply becomes

```
A(idx_row,:) = nan;
```

Comment: Thanks! As an extension, if all columns of a row are zeros, I want to make the entire row NaN. How can I do this? Input: [0 0 1; 0 0 0; 7 8 0; 0 0 0; 8 9 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0]; Output: [0 0 1; NaN NaN NaN ; 7 8 0; NaN NaN NaN ; 8 9 0; NaN NaN NaN ; NaN NaN NaN];

Answer (score 1):

The two argument find can find row index.

```
[r,~] = find(isinf(A) | isnan(A));
A(r,:) = nan;
```

Not sure it is more effective since I do not know how your loop looks, but my guess is that it will be fairly efficient at least. It is at least clean since the code is easy to read and requires only 2 rows of code. Note that `r` may contain duplicates, but that should not be a problem.

Comment: This works. Thanks! As an extension, if all columns of a row are zeros, I want to make the entire row NaN. How can I do this? Input: [0 0 1; 0 0 0; 7 8 0; 0 0 0; 8 9 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0]; Output: [0 0 1; NaN NaN NaN ; 7 8 0; NaN NaN NaN ; 8 9 0; NaN NaN NaN ; NaN NaN NaN];

Answer (score 0):

You can use [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/).

```
filter = zeros(size(A,1), 1); % Initialize a filter. 
for ii = 1:size(A,2)
    filter = filter | (isnan(A(:,ii)) | isinf(A(:,ii))); % If there is any element in the column that is nan or inf, set the element to one. 
end

B = A;
B(filter, :) = nan;   % Make the row that contains any NaN or inf all NaNs.
```